# Maintaining two code bases that are 90% the same installed on two different servers that must be isolated from each other?

Tags: git, dry, project-structure

We created a webapp for a client, deployed it to its own server, and it is now live.  Our business people just arranged a deal where we can use the same app, but it has to be on a different server and the look and feel must be rebranded.  As such, the only differences between the apps are the CSS and the database.  I am in charge of maintaining both installations.

Currently I have the code in a Git repo deployed to a Linode running Ubuntu server.  How could I set up the second copy of the site and still keep everything as DRY as possible?

I would prefer to not have to make bug fixes on the 90% of code that is shared and then remember what I did and copy the changes to a second repo.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a branch in git for one of the sites.

Or you can just factor out the things that have to be different so the sites share an identical code base and then each site's 'configuration' is managed separately (e.g. in its own git repo).

Answer (score 1):

Transform your config files with scripts. Keep a config file in source control that does not work in any platform. You want to fail fast.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common use case that Linux distributions or Android vendors have to deal with.

I think you have some commits in the "revamped" version to customize this one (one for css, images and i18n, another for configuration).

Your "clean" codebase should be the base of the "revamped".

This is what happen when you fork a project and want to integrate upstream modifications.

To achieve this your clean project is a proper git repo, the other is another which references the clean by a remote.

When a change is applied to the clean project, just fetch and rebase the other project.
This will apply customization commits to the lastest upstream version.

Please note that you still can have conflicts to resolve and that you have to test the result. It isn't magic but it will work 95% of the times.